# TFS SDK on Surface RT

Tags: tfs, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to make an application that will allow a user to initiate builds, see build info etc, and just general TFS based actions.

I've found a few guides on how to use the SDK... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx

But I can't use the TeamFoundation.*.dll's in the metro/win8 app... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302(v=vs.110).aspx

so, is there an alternative? Do they have a separate api? (you can access a tfs project via the web access, providing a web based alternative from doing it all in visual studio).

Thanks,
james.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows RT is an ARM based surface and the TFS SDK/OM is only available compiled for x86.  So, it will not work.

Windows Surface PRO available later will be x86 based.

The closest you could probably get is if you coded directly to the SOAP web service layer directly.  The TFS team is also starting to create RESTful http APIs with light http clients but that's a work in progress that's just starting.  That would be the long term approach available someday.

If you're creating a Windows store app, you should note that it's sandboxed.  The TFS team is looking into that as we transition toward REST and a more modern REST client.